# How to view a pdf file through url in angular 14

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pdf-viewer

How can I show a pdf file through a URL I have used the iframe but it is directly downloading the file,
I have checked it with ng2-pdf-viewer but it is not opening the URL, the URL is like this:-
https://borrowerfiles.file.core.windows.net/files/Ter_Stegen_6464910d6803200f51fa5e04_CE1000434/individual_kyc/4e7ebfbc-2138-4444-9eab-6e82ea1be577_19_05_23_083548.pdf?sv=2020-02-10&se=2023-05-24T05%3A59%3A17Z&sr=s&sp=r&sig=VQ668g6Dtbl1hQFxLQ82VQthnHje2VCq2W72TBI2qjk%3D

I have tried ng2-pdf-viewer, and I tried ngx-extended-pdf-viewer but this is a throwing error in angular 14 on compile time the error was Module '"ngx-extended-pdf-viewer"' has no exported member
'PdfViewerModule';